# Controller defined inside a module change all routes to its scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

If I define a route inside a module, like this:

```
class DrivenSignupPlugin::AccountController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Then all calls to `url_for` (including `redirect_to`) inside it will prefix the `:controller` parameter with `driven_signup_plugin/`.

This is not the desired behaviour as this controller uses many routes outside it. For example, `render_access_denied` is a method from `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this, add this method to the controller:

```
  def default_url_options
    # avoid rails' use_relative_controller!
    {use_route: '/'}
  end
```

For Rails 4.2+, something more complicated is needed:

```
  # inherit routes from core skipping use_relative_controller!
  def url_for options
    options[:controller] = "/#{options[:controller]}" if options.is_a? Hash and options[:controller]
    super options
  end 
  helper_method :url_for
```